# Need a label to output a number. C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to have my label output the monthly rate after it has been calculated through my formula.  I keep getting an error when I try to output the number.

```
double top = _principal * _interestRate / 1200.00;
double bottom =( 1 - Math.Pow(1.0 + _interestRate / 1200.0, -12.0     _numberOfyears));
double _monthlyRate = top / bottom;
lblMonthlyRate  = _monthlyRate ("C");
```

Comment: double bottom =( 1 - Math.Pow(1.0 + _interestRate / 1200.0, -12.0     _numberOfyears));  how does this line even compile? why is there not comma between -12 and _numberOfYears, or whats even going on here?

Comment: this does not compile, in the first place at all, fix your question

Comment: I had the same problem. I basically just isolated to display a double of varying value after I looked at it (which is the question anyway). However, he should have specified in the question it was WPF, because it took me looking at the title bar and seeing "wpf - Needed..." (I thought it was WinForm at first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lblMonthlyRate  = _monthlyRate ("C");
```

Should be (This is for Windows Forms):

```
lblMonthlyRate.Text = _monthlyRate.ToString("C");
```

EDIT Per your update to another answer:

Did you lose reference to System.Web.UI.WebControls?

EDIT 2:

I'm a dummy. This is WPF? You need (This is for WPF):

```
lblMonthlyRate.Content = _montlyRate.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
double top = _principal * _interestRate / 1200.00;
double bottom =( 1 - Math.Pow(1.0 + _interestRate / 1200.0, -12.0,    _numberOfyears));
double _monthlyRate = top / bottom;
lblMonthlyRate.Text  = _monthlyRate.ToString("C");
```

Comment: I have tried these and I get that Label doesn't contain a definition for Text and no extension method for Text. Also for monthly rate it keeps saying method name expected.

Comment: Check my answer. You might have lost a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lblMonthlyRate.Text  = _monthlyRate.ToString("C");
```

Comment: I have tried these and I get that Label doesn't contain a definition for Text and no extension method for Text.  Also for monthly rate it keeps saying method name expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblMonthlyRate  = _monthlyRate ("C");
```

Should be:

```
lblMonthlyRate.Content = _monthlyRate.ToString("C");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I posted it above as well when I saw the page title have "WPF" in it... versus the question.